# Do I need to add "https" to iOS info.plist and Android manifest files

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I've read the [React Native documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#canopenurl) on the `canOpenURL` method.
From what I understood I have to add `http://` and `https://` to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` and `AndroidManifest.xml` but it worked fine without me adding those values.

E.g. `canOpenURL('https://stackoverflow.com/');`

I tried to find iOS and Android specific documentation on that but I couldn't find a clear answer to that.

So do I actually need to add `http` and `https` to plist and manifest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to add those schemes.

`LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` was added to prevent apps from abusing the system to produce an "app inventory" by stealth.  Http and https do not reveal anything.  In fact there probably isn't much point in calling `canOpenUrl` for these schemes as you know that you can (Maybe the user could have removed all browsers from the device, but it seems an unlikely case).

Also, note that `canOpenUrl` doesn't check anything after the method; It doesn't tell you anything about the validity of the domain name or url path.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I am still wondering why React Native docs would say
"For web URLs, the protocol ("http://", "https://") must be set accordingly!"
Is it referring to something else?

Comment: I don't know.  Maybe it is different on Android?  Maybe they don't know what is required?